# nodemon runs only index.js file

Tags: node.js, express, nodemon

In my package.json file in the scripts section there is written “start”: “nodemon index.js”, but in my project there are also other files that process requests from the client, the problem is that only those routes that are defined in the file work index.js, why is this and how to fix it?

I tried putting the code of other files into a function, then exporting these functions and importing them in the index.js file and calling them. Only after that they started working, but it seems to me that this is very wrong.I want the code in other files to also work, but without importing it into the index.js file, because it seems to me that over time the index.js file will become very large

```
import express from "express";
const app = express();
const PORT = 8000;
import authorization from "./authorization.js";
import { connect_to_mysql } from "./connect_to_mysql.js";
import registration from "./registration.js";


app.use("/public", express.static("public"));

(async function() {
        await connect_to_mysql();
        await authorization();
        await registration();
        await upload();
    
        app.listen(PORT, () => console.log("server started"));
})()

export { app, express };
```

Comment: Your question isn't clear, and by the looks of it you don't understand the use of the app.use method.... Express is made to handle this with the Router feature... At which point you control different routes from different route files... Often people will segment out the middleware and have that in a different folder (maybe controllers)... Then the routes files will import the middleware and the index.js can just import the routes and use those routes with the app instance.

Answer (score 0):

In your `npm` script, you only run with `nodemon` the `index.js` file and not the others. The most correct way to do this is using express `Router` class to generate other endpoints (situated in different files) or exporting functions from other files to `index.js`. This file is the only one that is supposed to be ran, but you can refactor your code so that it's divided in different files.

Answer (score 0):

When working with ESModules, you have starting point (file, `index.js` for example) and each file you want to use must export something and being imported somewhere. Otherwise, the file just not being used.

If you don't want to overload the `index.js` file, simply create an express router in a separate file:

```
import express from "express";

const router = express.Router();

router.post("/example", (req, res) => res.send());


export default router;
```

And then use this router (in the `index.js` file):

```
import express from "express";

import router from "./routers/example";

const app = express();

app.use("/example", router);
```